# Django prevent data from passing in URL

Tags: django

I am new to Django and web dev. I am currently working on a textbox that a user will input data. Then they will click submit and I want that data to go to another page. However when they click the submit button, all the text ends up in the URL. The amount of text that will be passed in this text area is going to be thousands of characters. Is it possible to not allow it to appear in the url?

This is my textbox and submit button:

```
    <form action="{% url 'parsed' %}">
        <textarea name="fulltextarea" cols=40 rows=10></textarea>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='jsonparser-home'),
    path('parsed/', views.parsed, name="parsed")
]
```

views.py

```
def parsed(request):
    data = request.GET.get('fulltextarea')
    print(data)
    return render(request, 'jsonparser/parsed.html', {"json":data})
```

Now when I enter text into my text box and click the submit button my URL gets the data in it as:

`http://localhost:8000/parsed/?fulltextarea=wefwefallmydatasubmittedishere`

Is it possible to remove all of that in the URL?

Comment: Please use a POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally GET requests are used for simple things like searching, filtering, etc. A GET request should have *no* side effects. That means that normally a POST request should not result in new records being added to the database, update or remove records, etc.

Requests that *do* have side-effects, should be done through a POST request. These are then send in the *header* of the HTTP request. This is also done if the form contains *sensitive* data, like a password, since otherwise, a one could look over the shoulder and see the password in the querystring of the part.

You can make use of a POST request by specifying `method="POST"` in the `<form>`:

```
<form action="{% url 'parsed' %}" method="POST">
    <textarea name="fulltextarea" cols=40 rows=10></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

In the view, you can then access the data with:

```
def parsed(request):
    data = request.POST.get('fulltextarea')
    print(data)
    return render(request, 'jsonparser/parsed.html', {"json":data})
```

Answer (score 2):

add method="POST" in your form

```
<form action="{% url 'parsed' %}" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

replace:

```
data = request.GET.get('fulltextarea')
```

to

```
data = request.POST.get('fulltextarea')
```